# Problem: DUPLICATE_VALUE: duplicate value found: MessagingChannelId , where flow is running

Tags: visual-workflow

This error occurred when the flow tried to create records: DUPLICATE_VALUE: duplicate value found: MessagingChannelId duplicates value on record with id

Has anyone faced this problem?

Comment: [Here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000IRvSUSA1) the same seems to be observed in a context, where the problem is stated.